# PHP show drop down selected based on value

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu

I want to show a drop down selected for some value which is coming from database.

```
    <select name="plans">
       <option>MAP</option>
       <option>CP</option>
       <option>CPA</option>
       <option>CPF</option>
    </select>
```

Reading a value from database in PHP/Mysql, lets say "CPA", how do I show this option selected?

Comment: You need to give option value also for each option then you need to check with each option

Comment: did you mean    '<select name="plans" value="<?php echo 'CPA' ?>">'

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the `selected` attribute in `HTML`.

If for example the value you got from the database is assigned to a variable say `$val`,

Then you can do it as follows :

```
<select name="plans">
       <option <?php echo ($val == 'MAP')?"selected":"" ?> >MAP</option>
       <option <?php echo ($val == 'CP')?"selected":"" ?> >CP</option>
       <option <?php echo ($val == 'CPA')?"selected":"" ?> >CPA</option>
       <option <?php echo ($val == 'CPF')?"selected":"" ?> >CPF</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: How many times has it happened to you guys? You start an answer for a SO question and when you are almost done, a more or less identical answer appears from another great contibrutor and the time spent was some what in vain. Thats the greatness of SO though. Swift and often precise answers.

Comment: Maybe we need a tool to see how many people are currently writing an answer.

Comment: @Henkealg It has happened to me many time :-)

Answer (score 1):

You search for

```
<option selected>CPA</option>
```

I recommend you to read through some HTML beginner guides.

Answer (score 1):

```
$row->will contain the name of plans after query execution 

<select name="plans">
       <option value="MAP" <?php if($row['plans']=="MAP") echo selected;?>>MAP</option>
       <option value="CP" <?php if($row['plans']=="CP") echo selected;?>>CP</option>
       <option value="CPA">CPA</option>
       <option value="CPF">CPF</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as an example.

```
//$val = Value from database;

<select name="plans">
       <option <?php if(isset($val) && $val=="1") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="1" >MAP</option>
       <option <?php if(isset($val) && $val=="2") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="2" >CP</option>
       <option <?php if(isset($val) && $val=="3") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="3" >CPA</option>

 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<select name="plans">
   <option <?php echo ($value == "MAP")?"selected":"" ?> >MAP</option>
   <option <?php echo ($value == "CP")?"selected":"" ?> >CP</option>
   <option <?php echo ($value == "CPA")?"selected":"" ?> >CPA</option>
   <option <?php echo ($value == "CPF")?"selected":"" ?> >CPF</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the need to downvote it..??

Comment: It is the manners to tell the reason as well.....

Comment: it should be required!

Comment: moderators need to control this...It happend to me almost 5to 6 times

Comment: To make a comment on downvoting. It's useless to downvote without any comment... nobody knows why the downvote happend and you can't improve...

Comment: SO staff says always the community should help hisself. So I upvote now to make it equal :D

Comment: thanku @abimelex but it happnes so many of us...Modurators Need to search a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `selected` attribute in the `<option>` HTML tag.

Full code:

```
<?php

    $dbValue = 'CPA';

    $options = array
    (
        'MAP' => 'MAP',
        'CP' => 'CP',
        'CPA' => 'CPA',
        'CPF' => 'CPF'
    );

    echo '<select name="plans">';

    foreach ($options as $value => $option)
    {
        $selected = $value == $dbValue ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        echo "<option {$selected} value=\"{$value}\">{$option}</option>";
    }

    echo '</select>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put **selected** in for the option you want to be selected.

Like:

```
<select name="plans">
   <option>MAP</option>
   <option>CP</option>
   <option selected>CPA</option>
   <option>CPF</option>
</select>
```

When you build the above list, for each option you check whether it is the one in the database. And when it is, you add **selected**.