# Retain selected value in select box

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

How can I retain my selected option in a select box which is dynamically populated from database. I have seen many answers but mostly they are for static values.Here is my code for this,

```
  <select name="batchnumber" class="form-control"  id="batchno" required>   

         <option value="">select batch number</option>                 
       <?php 
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no,rpp_id FROM tbl_regn_prescribed_parameters where rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no  != 0");
                  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){   

           echo "<option value=" . $row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no'] . ">" . $row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no'] . "</option>";       
              }
        ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: do you mean after the form has been submitted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP show drop down selected based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207557/php-show-drop-down-selected-based-on-value)

Comment: Thanks for the time. Yes.. Once the form is submitted and results are shown , I want to keep the option as selected.

Comment: it's duplicated questions, I have seen such questions asked lots of times

Comment: @JigarShah I checked the link you posted but this shows method if the options are static. Check my question details .

Comment: @MahdiYounesi Check my question details.

Comment: @Anand, I have read your question, but I thought you would be able to make it dynamic by yourself .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi we can do this simply by adding if condition,

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{   
    if($_REQUEST['batchnumber'] == $row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no'])
    {
        echo "<option selected value=" . $row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no'] . ">" . $row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no'] . "</option>";       
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<option value=" . $row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no'] . ">" . $row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no'] . "</option>";  
    }

}
```

**But try to use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_***

Comment: @Anand happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The selected property in html will help you out here.

All you have to do is check if the rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no of the row is equals to current selection.

```
$currently_selected_rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no=123;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){   

$selected=$row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no']==$currently_selected_rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no?("selected"):("");

echo "<option $selected value=" . $row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no'] . ">" . $row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no'] . "</option>";

}
```

So basically get the current rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no to a variable and check if row's value equals to current value in every row. If it matches, add "selected" prop to option.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="batchnumber" class="form-control"  id="batchno" required>          
   <?php 
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no,rpp_id FROM tbl_regn_prescribed_parameters where rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no  != 0");
   $selected="";
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
   {  
     $selected=$_POST['batchnumber']==$row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no']?"selected":""; 
     echp "<option value=".$row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no']." ".$selected.">".$row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no']."</option>";   

   }
   ?></select>
```

Form method whether it GET or POST